# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I want the user to type in all data that is displayed (the columns from the database), fill them in and submit. I cant get the Id and CompanyID to get auto generated either with `HTML.HiddenFor` element.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition..

Model:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.Contact

<h2>Create Contact</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)</td>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyID)</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" class="btn-primary" value="Create" />
}
```

Controller:

```
using Arbetsprov_Sublime___Andre_Kordasti.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Arbetsprov_Sublime___Andre_Kordasti.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Contact model)
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sublime;Integrated Security=True");
            connection.Open();

            var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact Values('" + model.Id + "','" + model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + " " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are currently taking information from your database & filling it in an object. you should be either 1) map your contact object to an entity framework or 2) create an "insert into Contact(column names) values()" type of query & fire that query.

Comment: I dont want to use EF. Yes I have made the INSERT statement, but how do I bind them to my textboxes in the view?

Comment: **WARNING: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.** You should use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact(Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,CompanyId) Values('" + model.Id + "','" + model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + " " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

if there is a column that has to be autoGenerated you have to tell the values which u are giving for which column they are so that sql then knows that the attributes which are not mentioned should be autoGenerated

Comment: I think my ID is auto generated, how do I fix this?

Comment: var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact(FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,CompanyId) Values("'+ model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + " " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I get error: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Comment: If u used this query that i send you in this comment it was wrong sorry , try the one i send you as second answer.

Comment: **WARNING: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection**. You should use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Contact Table "ID" Column Value repeater. ex: current id is already have

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email , Phone, CompanyID) Values('" + model.Id + "','" + model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + " " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or (if your table id column is auto increment then)

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName, Email , Phone, CompanyID) Values('" + model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + " " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I think my ID is auto generated, how do I fix this?

Comment: I get error: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Answer (score 0):

Try not sending the ID to it:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contact(FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,CompanyId) Values("'"+ model.FirstName + "',' " + model.LastName + "','" + model.Email + "',' " + model.Phone + "','" + model.CompanyID + "')", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And if it doesn't work, please share the exception thrown.

The query you shared in your comment had some commas missing ','.

So

```
INSERT INTO tbl(Column1,Column2,Column3) values ('value1''value2'+','value3')
```

will give you the same error, because you mentioned 3 columns, but gave only 2 values.